# What software should I use to encrypt my storage drives with what configurations given encryption always fails?

Tags: windows-10, bitlocker, disk-encryption, veracrypt

I suspect that my use-case is NOT that unique. I have a PC with 1 NVMe SSD and two SATA SSDs. Each drive has Windows 10 installed on it. I need each drive to be encrypted. I have tried both Veracrypt and Bitlocker, but both have ultimately failed, and I am boggled as to why.

I have tried to encrypt with Bitlocker perhaps over 50 times. The encryption works for one hour, two, maybe a whole day - then, ultimately, without fail, the encryption information gets "lost". What this translates to is that the Password no longer works (Bitlocker does not recognize it as the correct password) and the recovery key is similarly useless. Always, on fifty or more different attempts, this happens. It happens with one drive, then another drive, then another, and I am forced to format the drive and re-encrypt it. *Sometimes* I will get an actual error code `No Bootable Volume Found`. But this is rare.

I suspect this is because my motherboard does not support TPM. Whenever I turn on bitlocker for the first time, I must edit the group policy to [Allow BitLocker without a compatible TPM](https://www.howtogeek.com/6229/how-to-use-bitlocker-on-drives-without-tpm/). I cannot imagine why this would be an issue, but that is my best guess.

Veracrypt just fails alltogether to encrypt my drive. It complains that "Windows does not appear to be installed on the drive from which it boots." I ignored the error message and continued anyways, just to see what happens, and lo and behold, on the test run, my password was not being accepted.

Okay. So, my ideal scenario is to encrypt all three drives and then, on startup, be able to choose which drive I would like to access, and enter the password for it to decrypt it.

I have tried many different things, but I am not sure if they are relevant to the issue. I have tried formatting each drive, and then installing Windows on each on while the others are unplugged from the machine. I have tried installing Windows while each are plugged into the machine. I have even tried installing Windows on each drive on three separate machines, only to join them once they have been fully configured (installed windows and encrypted the drive).

Always I get an issue where the password suddenly does not get recognized. I am at my wit's end... not sure what to do about this. I honestly have even tried just having one drive for some time, and *still* the encryption eventually fails.

What am I doing wrong? How do I get this damn thing to work? Again, I would like to have each drive encrypted with its own encryption and its own password, separate from all other drives. The drives should not be able to access the content of the other. And of course, they should be encrypted. I should be able to choose which drive I want to boot into. At this point, I don't care if I can't do it through Windows Boot Manager - if I have to switch the drive at BIOS startup, that's fine with me, I just want to encrypt it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Once the password stops working, does it never start working again?

Comment: Do you have everything updated? Windows/drivers etc?

Comment: “I suspect this is because my motherboard does not support TPM.” - BitLocker doesn’t require TPM. Furthermore, most of not all processors, support fTPM which supports the TPM 2.0 requirements for BitLocker.

Comment: Have you tried the Startup Key functionality in Bitlocker?

Comment: @Gantendo As for your first question, there has only been one time where I attempted for *several* times (approximately a week) before just reformatting. In that instance, no, it would not let me login. Second question, yes everything is updated of that I am sure, even my BIOS. For your third question, I am not sure, I do not know what Startup Key functionality is in bitlocker.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/information-protection/bitlocker/prepare-your-organization-for-bitlocker-planning-and-policies#bitlocker-key-protectors see both tables and https://www.howtogeek.com/262744/how-to-use-a-usb-key-to-unlock-a-bitlocker-encrypted-pc/

Comment: @Gantendo How is this going to be different than a password? Seems like the password becomes the key on your USB. I used recovery keys generated by bitlocker and it similarly did not work.

Comment: That is explained in the links above.

Comment: You report using 3 drives EACH with Windows 10 on them. Is this a multi boot setup? Which drive has a bootloader? If this is not multi boot and you just have 3 drives in one computer with Windows 10 running just once on it, how are you encrypting the NON-OS drives? Please add this and other requested info to the question itself to make it more complete and more clear.

Comment: @music2myear okay, I am not 100% sure if this is a multiboot setup. Each drive has Windows 10 on it. Shouldn't each drive then have a bootloader on it? None of my drives are NON-OS drives; each has a Windows 10 OS on it

Comment: How do your choose which Windows 10 to run?

Comment: @music2myear When I boot up my computer, Windows Boot Manager comes up and I can choose an OS/Drive to boot into

Comment: So one of your drives contains the boot information for all of the OSes on the other drives. You need to keep this in mind and do your research regarding encryption with a multi boot environment as your target. You're not the first person to try this, and I'm pretty I've seen others asking questions about the same setup here.